# Time complexity of nested for loop inside while loop

Tags: time-complexity

If there is a nested for loop inside while loop like this:

```
while(condition)
   for(i=0; i<size; i++)
```

the size in the for loop is increasing every time the for loop is being executed, starting at 1,2,...,n-1
and the while loop runs n-1 times.

That means that the time complexity is O(n^3)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by *every time the for loop is being executed* you mean every time the `while(condition)` triggers a new run of the `for` loop, then the time complexity is [image: 1].

That is, if you increment a counter inside the inner for loop, it will be incremented [image: n] *= n choose 2* times. But because constant factors and lower order terms are omitted in big O notation, we can just write [image: 3].

For illustration, consider this Python 2.7 implementation (I converted the outer `while` loop + `size` increment into a for loop):

```
n = 10
counter = 0

for size in range(1, n):
    for i in range(0, size):
        counter += 1
        print i,
    print
print

print "counter =", counter
print "n choose 2 =", (n * (n - 1)) / 2
```

Output:

```
0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

counter = 45
n choose 2 = 45
```

Try running it with different values of *n* to see that the formula holds true.